# Excel Formula for averaging by weekday

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to summarize 2 years worth of data quickly by month. What I want to do is to average only the values from Monday to Friday for each month.

[image: data_image]

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: And mock data with expected output.

Comment: I don't have any code since I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you change column b to be a calculated day of week field like so:

```
=TEXT(B2, "ddd")
```

And you insert a new column c field that is calculated month like so:

```
=TEXT(B2, "mmm")
```

You can then use an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) to solve your problem.  You might need to modify the formula slight based upon your data but the follow formula should work.

```
=AVERAGE(IF((C:C<>"Sat")*(C:C<>"Sun")*(D:D="May"),E:E))
```

Keep in mind because this is an array formula you have to hit Ctrl+Shirt+Enter on a PC or Command+Return on a Mac.  Basically what it is saying is that if column C is not Sat and not Sun and column D is May, then average the value in column E.

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult.

Try this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(B2:B99,2)<6)+0,D2:D99)/SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(B2:B99,2)<6)+0)
```

I have the last row as 99 but you can just change that 99 to whatever your last row is that you need.

EDIT:

Just noticed you said "by month". The formula above will take the average column D where column B is a weekday. To modify for a specific month, the formula just needs to be slightly modified to account for the month also. See below, this shows how to do it for the month of May. (Month = 5) I broke it up into two lines so it is easier to read.

```
= SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(B2:B99,2)<6)+0,(MONTH(B2:B99)=5)+0,D2:D99)
  /SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(B2:B99,2)<6)+0,(MONTH(B2:B99)=5)+0)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: POC]

Similar to peter's answer, use the following formula in K2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(B:B,1)>1)*(WEEKDAY(B:B)<7)*(MONTH(B:B)=MONTH(DATEVALUE("01-"&$J$2&"-2017")))*(D:D))/SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(B:B,1)>1)*(WEEKDAY(B:B)<7)*(MONTH(B:B)=MONTH(DATEVALUE("01-"&$J$2&"-2017"))))
```

Warnings:  Despite not being a CSE /ARRAY formula, SUMPRODUCT performs array like calculations within its brackets.  As such, full column references like B:B should not be used.  Instead B:B should be adjusted to match the needs of your data.  In this case it should be B2:B22.

In the sumproduct formula above, the `*` are acting like `AND` statements.  It evaluates a logical comparison to either true or false.  If true or false is then put through a math operation, true values become 1 and false values become 0.  Therefore only rows where everything is true are counted.  The last step of the sumproduct is to sum all the results.  Therefore all rows containing a false will become zero and not affect the summation.

The tid bit in the formula that refers to `J2` basically converts what is assumed to be a month in text to a date that can be recognized by excel which then converts it to a numeric value which can then be compared to the month in your date list.  Now the only caveat here is that its every month of year irregardless of the year.  If you need a month from a specific year you will need the formula adjusted.